# Use of pre-commit with PyCharm

Tags: python, git, pycharm, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I am trying to launch my pre-commit hooks from "commit" button in PyCharm (v. 2020.2).
I use a conda venv (created with `conda create -n py38 python=3.8`) where I installed modules with `pip install`.

My `.pre-commit-config.yaml` reads:

```
repos:
- repo: local
  hooks:
  - id: black
    name: black
    language: system
    entry: black --check
    types: [python]

  - id: isort
    name: isort
    language: system
    entry: isort --check-only
    types: [python]
```

I use `local` repo here because I will push my code to an intranet repository not connected to the internet.

Running `pre-commit run --all-files` runs fine from the command line on my local machine. But when I try to commit from PyCharm ([image]), it raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None, File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\__main__.py", line 1, in   
    from pre_commit.main import main
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\main.py", line 13, in   
    from pre_commit.commands.autoupdate import autoupdate
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\commands\autoupdate.py", line 14, in   
    from pre_commit.clientlib import InvalidManifestError
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\clientlib.py", line 16, in   
    from pre_commit.error_handler import FatalError
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\error_handler.py", line 10, in   
    from pre_commit.store import Store
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\store.py", line 4, in   
    import sqlite3
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in   
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "c:\bib\envs\py38\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in   
    from _sqlite3 import * 
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.
```

I think that [this bug report](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1329) on `pre-commit`'s github is of particular relevance. If I understand well, it hints that PyCharm is not actually loading the venv and hence not finding installed packages in this environment. No solution is proposed though.

Anyone has a solution for that?

Comment: What folder are you in in your PyCharm terminal? Sometimes that can get ya.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @zerecees. I am not sure I answering to your question, but let me try. When I open my project, I open the folder containing my `.git` directory. This folder also contains my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file. Except from this I do not specify a working directory anywhere else. When I click on the 'Terminal' tab at the bottom left of the PyCharm window, it opens a prompt in my project directory. This is where I want to be.

Comment: (maintainer here) -- this is a bug in conda, I'd suggest using pre-commit from a non-conda environment if you're calling it from an IDE: https://github.com/conda-forge/pre-commit-feedstock/issues/9

Comment: I think you can activate conda environment in the terminal and start PyCharm from the same command line instance with `PyCharm\bin\pycharm.bat`. This way IDE and all processes spawned by it will inherit the environment setup made by conda.

Comment: Thank you both. The workaround you propose Pavel works indeed. I did not tested the solutions presented in the link shared by @AnthonySottile but I suppose they will work as well. I will test and update.